# Google sheets remove text are multiple certain words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im looking to remove text after certain words.

I currently have this function which ive found on here:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(D3,FIND(" USD",D3)))
```

But i would add a multiple list of words to this function such as GBP NPV etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D3,"\s+(?:USD|GBP|NPV).*","")
```

Reference: [`REGEXREPLACE` Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)